Translate VBA function in Python
I have VBA function and I'm trying to convert this application in Python.
Now I need to translate the following VBA code:
Dim R_SH(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Double

in Python.
I tried to write the following Python code but I think that is not correct:
w, h = 2, 3
R_SH = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]

Could we support me?

Why do you think that is not correct? R_SH would give you a 2-dimensional array of width w and height h, so setting w = 3 and h = 3 would give you the correct result.

Also, if you're working with a lot of typed data, you might want to look into numpy, which works well for typed multidimensional-array and provides easier operations.

In Python, arrays are 0-indexed. They start from 0 not 1.
To create an equivalent VBA array R_SH(1 To 3, 1 To 3), you need to create a 3x3 array in Python.
At the moment you're creating a 3x2 array, here's how you create a 3x3 array:
w, h = 3, 3
R_SH = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]

